# Difference between list of lists

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two lists

```
A=[['1','1'],['2','1'],['3','2']]

B=[['1','1'],['2','2']]
```

I want to perform A-B operation on these comparing only first element.

so A-B should give

```
Output=[['3', '2']]
```

So far, I could do only on row comparison

```
[x for x in A if not x in B]
```

which gives output as `[['2', '1'], ['3', '2']]`

Comment: Is it possible for duplicate elements like [['1', '1'], ['1', '2'], ['2', '2']]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
>>> [i for i in A if not any(i[0] == k for k, _ in B)]
[['3', '2']]
```

`any()` is used to check if the first element of each list is the same as any other value in every list in `B`. If it is, it returns True, but as we want the opposite of this, we use `not any(...)`

Comment: just curious to know, is the present solution computationally expensive compared to the previous solution you provided?

Comment: @JohnGalt The reason I swapped solutions is because my other one was incorrect. It would also compare the second value in the list (in `B`), which you don't want

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)  and set difference here:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dic1 = OrderedDict((k[0],k) for k in A)
>>> [dic1[x] for x in set(dic1) - set(y[0] for y in B)]
[['3', '2']]
```

Overall complexity is going to be `O(max(len(A), len(B)))`

If order doesn't matter then a normal dict is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of a different list comprehension

```
A=[['1','1'],['2','1'],['3','2']]
B=[['1','1'],['2','2']]
b = dict(B)
output_list = [item for item in A if item[0] not in b]
```

This is order preserving as well and can work even if there are duplicate fist elements in the inner list of A. Also it can be extended to check for exact pair if needed like this:

```
A=[['1','1'],['2','1'],['3','2']]
B=[['1','1'],['2','2']]
b = dict(B)
output_list = [item for item in A if item[0] not in b or b[item[0]] != item[1]]
```